# Cross Site Scripting & filter request asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to write a generic routine which will filter cross site scripting related character.
i found one that is in java. i dont know java.

### here is java code

```
package com.greatwebguy.filter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class CrossScriptingFilter implements Filter {
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
}
public void destroy() {
    this.filterConfig = null;
}
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(new RequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
}
```

}

```
package com.greatwebguy.filter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
public final class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
    super(servletRequest);
}
public String[] getParameterValues(String parameter) {
  String[] values = super.getParameterValues(parameter);
  if (values==null)  {
              return null;
      }
  int count = values.length;
  String[] encodedValues = new String[count];
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             encodedValues[i] = cleanXSS(values[i]);
   }
  return encodedValues;
}
public String getParameter(String parameter) {
      String value = super.getParameter(parameter);
      if (value == null) {
             return null;
              }
      return cleanXSS(value);
}
public String getHeader(String name) {
    String value = super.getHeader(name);
    if (value == null)
        return null;
    return cleanXSS(value);
}
private String cleanXSS(String value) {
            //You'll need to remove the spaces from the html entities below
    value = value.replaceAll("<", "& lt;").replaceAll(">", "& gt;");
    value = value.replaceAll("\\(", "& #40;").replaceAll("\\)", "& #41;");
    value = value.replaceAll("'", "& #39;");
    value = value.replaceAll("eval\\((.*)\\)", "");
    value = value.replaceAll("[\\\"\\\'][\\s]*javascript:(.*)[\\\"\\\']", "\"\"");
    value = value.replaceAll("script", "");
    return value;
}
```

}

```
<filter>
<filter-name>XSS</filter-name>
<display-name>XSS</display-name>
<description></description>
<filter-class>com.greatwebguy.filter.CrossScriptingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>XSS</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

the url from where i got this code 
http://greatwebguy.com/programming/java/simple-cross-site-scripting-xss-servlet-filter/

anyone can give me the tips to convert the code to asp.net & c# or write class from scratch which mimic the above functionality.
thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with just HtmlEncoding all user-supplied content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-site scripting can be avoided easily by ensuring that any user submitted content is HTML encoded prior to being rendered in the page. Usually this would be achieved by consistently using the `<%:` instead of the `<%=` ASPX tag to ensure that encoding is applied to the content. Attempting to "clean" input is doomed to failure. Rendering that input correctly is all that is required.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has a good article '[How to prevent Cross-Site scripting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx)'

You don't need half of that (Java) code to achieve the same result in asp.net.

**Edit:** as per Spenders recommendation here's another link, this time for [MVC](http://blog.codeville.net/2007/12/19/aspnet-mvc-prevent-xss-with-automatic-html-encoding/)

Note: I'd still read the first article though for understanding the principles.

Comment: Top of the linked page states. "This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained." Perhaps better to link to a newer resource.